# What is up with dev.stackapps.com?

Tags: bug, status-declined, stackapps

I went to log into http://dev.stackapps.com and it said that the Web Apps site was in private beta. (Which I already knew.)

Why does this show up for StackApps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't support random access of our dev tier.

Comment: What a strange practice :)